# How to make concatenation within javascript function

Tags: javascript

I want to call the javascript functions like bbb(a1), bbb(a2), bbb(a3)......
through the function

```
function sss()
{
    for (i=1;i<=3;i++){

        bbb(a.i)

    } 
}

sss();
```

There must be many errors in the above code. What should be the correct syntax? Specially in bbb(a.i) i.e., to concatenate 'a' with variable 'i'.

Comment: JavaScript's string concatenation operator is `+`.

Comment: `a + i` will do string concatenation between the variables `a` and `i`. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Having dynamically named variables is a sign that you should be using an array or object instead.

Comment: Your question is not obvious. What is `a`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure of your intentions, but re-reading your question a couple of times, I think you're looking to build a string out of the iterator variable `i` to pass to `bbb()`. If so, you'd want this:

```
function sss() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        bbb("a" + i);
    } 
}
```

This will effectively do:

```
bbb("a1");
bbb("a2");
bbb("a3");
```

Also note the introduction of `var` before `i = 1` -- you definitely don't want to accidentally create global iterator variables.

Comment: ya, this is my intention.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you right, there aren't any *syntax* errors, but there are a couple of others:

```
function sss()
{
    var i; // <=== Declare `i`
    for (i=1;i<=3;i++){

        bbb(a[i]); // <=== Use [i] to access `a[1]`, `a[2]`, etc.

    } 
}

sss();
```

Note that if `a` is a normal, non-sparse array, you probably want:

```
    for (i=0;i<=a.length;i++){
```

In JavaScript, you can access properties using dot syntax with a literal (`obj.foo`), or bracketed syntax with what is technically coerced to a string (`obj["foo"]`). The second syntax is what we typically use for arrays, using `a[0]`, `a[1]`, etc. (which are *technically*, *theoretically* coerced to `a["0"]`, `a["1"]`, etc., because [regular JavaScript arrays aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html).)

Comment: You might want to mention the "off by 1" thingy as well ;)

Comment: ...assuming accessing an array by an index is the question, but given the "to concatenate 'a' with variable 'i'" part of the question, I'm not so sure.

Comment: @Cory: Yeah, I went out on a limb that "concatenate" was a non-native speaker mistake, could easily be wrong.

Comment: My understanding was that he wants to pass the **strings** `"a1"`, then `"a2"`, and so on (i.e. `bbb('a' + i)`). Could be either...

Comment: "I want to call the javascript functions like bbb(a1)"... maybe OP is looking for `bbb("a" + i)` in the loop?

Comment: @Cory: Easily could be. I was working from the later (and contraditory) *"Specially in bbb(a.i) ..."* :-)